# NHibernate query to find records having some equal columns and some different in single table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Trying to write a fluent query to accomplish the following: find services provided for the same student, on the same date but with different code.
The sql query can look like :

```
select * from [Service] t1
where exists (
select 
    * 
from [Service] t2 
where 
t1.StudentId = t2.StudentId and
t1.ServiceDate = t2.ServiceDate and 
t1.ProcedureCodeId <> t2.ProcedureCodeId )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note: the code is from memory without compiler, has to be tweaked

```
Service serviceAlias = null;

var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Service>()
    .WhereRestrictonOn(s => s.Student.Id).EqProperty(() => serviceAlias.Student.Id)
    .WhereRestrictonOn(s => s.Date).EqProperty(() => serviceAlias.Date)
    .WhereRestrictonOn(s => s.ProcedureCode.Id).NotEqProperty(() => serviceAlias.ProcedureCode.Id);

var results = session.QueryOver(() => serviceAlias)
    .WithSubqueries.WhereExists(subquery)
    .List();
```